# About menu crash after press it

Tags: android-studio

I do not know what error I have. I already put MainActivity between new Intent and this.

This is my mainactivity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
  switch (item.getItemId()){
      case R.id.:
          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          break;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

This is AboutActivity.java

```
package com.example.zakatcalculator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class AboutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewLink);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

And this is AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".AboutActivity"
    android:exported="false">

</activity>
```

When I press about button, then its crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch (item.getItemId()){
  case R.id.about:
      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
      break;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

replace **R.id.** to this **R.id.about** and try again.

Comment: its still crash

Comment: this is error from logcat.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)' on a null object reference